# List of .png files in html and js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a something in my project, that display the images that ends with .png

Currently, I have this part of code :

```html
  <h2>Files list :</h2>
  <p id="list"></p>
  <script>
    import 'path';

    const EXTENSION = '.png';

    const targetFiles = files.filter(file => {
      return path.extname(file).toLowerCase() === EXTENSION;
    });

   if(targetFiles == "") {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "No images found.";
   } else {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = targetFiles;
   }
</script>
```

The issue here is that I can't find an alternative solution for the `path` package that is working for web and can help me with this.

Comment: You can't use `path` in the browser

Comment: I know I can't, I'm looking for an alternative that I can use in the web instead.

Comment: imagine what kind of security hole it would be to have websites accessing your local file system

Comment: this site wont be public, it will be localy on a pc.

Comment: Still, cannot be done. You have to use a file input or [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)

Comment: Where are your images? I mean, where did you put those images?

Comment: You need to use code on your server to access files on your server (e.g. NodeJS) and produces something you can use. Alternatively you can make requests to the server from the browser for folders/files, dealing with the errors, until you come across a folder and file that exists. Doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access any file system through a web application, client or server, no matter how "localy on a pc" it will be.

To do the kind of thing you're describing, you need a second application to handle the file system lookup and/or transfer (presumably, you also want to see the images, right?). And then the two applications can talk over AJAX calls or web-sockets to request the look ups and download the needed files.

Comment: No, I mean to access the directory of the files, not the local files.

Comment: "The directory"? What directory? There's only one? Use pictures and code if you can't explain your problem in words because as far as I can tell I've answered what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry. I mean to the directory of all of the files (index.html, main.css, main.js). This is where I want to access the files. In the same directory are also some .png files.

Comment: @ZeRealOne — A directory is part of a file system. The first paragraph of this answer still applies.

Comment: Specifically, **that's the server file system**. You do not, under any circumstances, have access to that from a web application.

Answer (score 0):

1. step 1 for HTML

   `img src=` for pic
2. step 2

   use the internet to look for picture or go to gallery to find a picture go to your file
3. step3

   use the `img src` for the picture
   example
   `img src =a`